# Cocoon populating form in reverse order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

Example:
I have a form_for "Party" where you can create many "People", using Cocoon to build the fields_for People.  I create 3 people in this order:

Person1

Person2

Person3

I save the form, and then go back to edit the form.  I am presented with the people in this order:

Person3

Person2

Person1

Is there any reason for this?  I assume that it just has to do with the way cocoon recalls the data, most recent to oldest.  However, I would like the form to show the People in the same order that they were created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a default scope to your `person.rb` like this:

```
default_scope { order('created_at ASC') }
```